# Split csv file with correct data type in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to read this csv file in pyspark and make sure the x[2] and x[3] are read as integers. Currently, they are read as string. What is the best way to convert and keep line.split()?

I tried count = lines.map(lambda x: (int(x[2]),int(x[3]))) and kept getting an error message.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

#Initiate Spark Settings/Content
set1 = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("AR")
f = SparkContext(conf = set1)

#Initiate RDD
lines = f.textFile("file.csv").map(lambda line: line.split(","))

count = lines.map(lambda x: (x[2],x[3]))

count = count.collect()
for i in count:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Don't keep us hanging. What's the error?

Comment: @drum The output is string and I am trying to make convert to int! 

['10705', '2453']
['2989', '1855']

and I want:
[10705, 2453]
[2989. 1855]

Thanks.